# How to calculate prediction probability in python and NLTK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nltk

I am trying to calculate each prediction probability in SVM model by using `LinearSVC` and `OneVsRestClassifier` but getting the error

`AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'`

tried code:

```
model = Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(class_weight="balanced")))])

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_train.shape
pred = model.predict(X_test)

probas = model.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Also tried:

```
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

LinearSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear',probability=True))
prob_1 = LinearSVC_classifier.predict_proba(X_test)
```

but still getting error `AttributeError: 'SklearnClassifier' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'`

Please suggestion for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your Linear SVM:

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, make_pipeline
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

word_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))
features = FeatureUnion([('words', word_vectorizer), ])
calibrated_svc = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(), method='sigmoid', cv=3)
pipeline = make_pipeline(features, calibrated_svc)
pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y)
predicted = pipeline.predict_proba(test_x)
```

or with Logistic Regression:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

word_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))
features = FeatureUnion([('words', word_vectorizer), ])
pipeline = make_pipeline(features, LogisticRegression())
pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y)
predicted = pipeline.predict_proba(test_x)
```

Comment: I am getting error: `ValueError: Requesting 3-fold cross-validation but provided less than 3 examples for at least one class.` in this line: `pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y)`. I have updated my data format. please suggest how to solve?

Comment: @user10468005 try 'from sklearn.model_selection import KFold' , 'kf = KFold(n_splits=3)' , 'calibrated_svc = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(), method='sigmoid', cv=kf)'

Answer (score 0):

Simply because 'SKlearnClassifier' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

You can predict probability this way,

```
 classifier.classify_many(test)

 for pdist in classifier.prob_classify_many(test):
...     print('%.4f %.4f' % (pdist.prob('x'), pdist.prob('y')))
```

code from [here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/classify.html)

Comment: getting error `AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'classify_many'` I have done this: `model.classify_many(test_data)

for pdist in model.prob_classify_many(test_data):
    print('%.4f %.4f' % (pdist.prob('x'), pdist.prob('y')))`