# How to improve speed of the program for large data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, stanford-nlp

I am trying to calculate the prediction probability. I have wrote a program which is calculating but speed is very slow and taking so much time for large dataset.

The aim is to calculate each prediction probability in the SVM model by using `LinearSVC` and `OneVsRestClassifier` but getting the error

`AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'`

Due to the above error, I have tried below

**Code**

```
from sklearn import svm

model_1 = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

X_1 = df["Property Address"]
lb = LabelEncoder()
X_2 = lb.fit_transform(X_1)

y_1 = df["Location_Name"]
y_2 = lb.fit_transform(y_1)

test_1 = test["Property Address"]
lb = LabelEncoder()
test_1 = lb.fit_transform(test_1)

X_2= X_2.reshape(-1, 1)
y_2= y_2.reshape(-1, 1)
test_1 = test_1.reshape(-1, 1)

model_1.fit(X_2, y_2)

results = model_1.predict_proba(test_1)[0]

# gets a dictionary of {'class_name': probability}
prob_per_class_dictionary = dict(zip(model.classes_, results))
```

Is there any other way for the same task? please suggest

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is your code slow or does it raise an error? Two very different problems.

Comment: I have posted a post but didn't get the solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040262/how-to-calculate-prediction-probability-in-python-and-nlp]. I have written a code which is very slow. I am not getting any error in above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sklearns [CalibratedClassifierCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html#sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV) if you need to use to the `predict_proba` method.

Or you could use [Logistic Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

If your issue is related to speed, try consider using the `LinearSVC` in `sklearn.svm` instead of `SVC(kernel='linear')`. It is faster.

Comment: How to calculate prediction probability by using `LinearSVC` ?

Comment: Did you try for e.g: calibrated_svc = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(), method='sigmoid', cv=3) ? Then fit it, and use predict_proba

Comment: yes, getting error: `ValueError: Requesting 3-fold cross-validation but provided less than 3 examples for at least one class.` - code: `calibrated_svc.fit(X_2, y_2)`

Comment: Do you understand the error? If you dont want to use the calibrated_svc, just use sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression as your model.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in another answer, `LinearSVC` is faster than `SVC(kernel='linear')`.

Regarding probability, SVC doesn't have `predict_proba()`. Instead, you have to set its `probability` hyperparameter to `True`. [Link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)

**Tip:** SVM is preferred for small datasets, so prefer to use other algorithms to handle large datasets.